# How to remove JFrame and show other ons after X seconds? (Java)

Tags: java, netbeans

When the user finishes to use my app, a "Thank You" screen is shown.
My problem is that I want to hide this screen after 5 seconds, and show the "Welcome" screen of the app.

How can I do this? What event should I listen to?

(I'm programming in Java, using NetBeans IDE)

Thanks,
Tomer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing Timer could to this.  You would create a timer that does not repeat (call setRepeats(false) on the Timer), and in its ActionListener's actionPerformed method, call setVisible(false) or dispose() on your second window.  The Swing tutorials will show you how to use this: [Swing Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

But I have to admit that many (myself included) don't really like apps where windows swap like that. You may be better off using a CardLayout to swap JPanel views in a stable JFrame. Again, you could use a Swing Timer to tell the layout to swap "cards".  For more on this: [CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Best of luck!

Comment: +1 for I have to admit that many (myself included) don't really like apps where windows swap like that. Also, when I am done with an app, 5 seconds is quite a long time to be shown a thank you message.